# Custom server response instead of OK . Android file upload

Tags: android, file-upload, server-response

i'm creating an android application which upload files to web server . my code is working successfully but i'm getting server response message "OK" but i want it "success" or something else which i write on php echo but I am not sure how to do that... my php script is

```
<?php
$file_path = "uploads/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

?>

and my code is...

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    final String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    long sentBytes=0;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+filePath);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+filePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),serverResponseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +"http://onsitesupport.info/diary/uploads/" + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
           // Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    } // End else block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    String stringResponse = sb.toString();
    Log.d("response string:", stringResponse);
```